# Update column in CartoDB with value from another table

Tags: carto

I am trying to update the column 'lt_dispatch_level' in my table "inland" with the values from another table "current_obs" that has a corresponding column 'lt_dispatch_level'.  However when I run this SQL query:

`INSERT INTO inland
(lt_dispatch_level, timestamp)
SELECT lt_dispatch_level, timestamp
FROM current_obs;`

I get the values from current_obs added in as a second row, with null values being aded in the first row.  I attached an image of what this looks like.

[image]

What do I need to change in my SQL query to get my values in the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Update](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html#AEN82105) query, something like below,

```
UPDATE inland
SET lt_dispatch_level = current_obs.lt_dispatch_level,
  timestamp = current_obs.timestamp
FROM current_obs
WHERE current_obs.{common column} = inland.{common column}
AND inland.cartodb_id= 1
```

Comment: This query is not working for me and I can't figure out why. Do I need to fill in a matching column name in the {}s?  I have matching columns in both tables (lt_dispatch_level, timestamp) and the table names are correct.

Comment: Nevermind that,  I just solved it by creating a matching column in my current_obs table.  Thank you for your help!